# Windows Shell extension works for some file types but not others

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I tried asking this before and it got closed, so I'll try again and be more specific this time.

I'm using Windows 7 and Visual C++ 2012. If I download the Microsoft example code for writing a shell extension context menu from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a and build it for 64 bit, register the DLL with RegSvr32, then right-click a .cpp file it works - a new command is shown in the context menu. In the dllmain.cpp file there are two references to the file extension ".cpp", if I change these to ".png", un-register the dll, rebuild it, register again, and right-click a png file then it works for that, the menu command is shown. Now if I change it to ".dat" then it doesn't work, there is no menu command shown. If I put message boxes at various points in the code then for .dat files none are shown, no code in the DLL appears to run. I've checked in the registry and as far as I can see it is registered correctly for the .dat file type, the same way it is when I try it for the other file types.

The registry is setup when the DLL is registered. When I do this for .dat files it looks like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dat
  (Default)=(value not set)
  NoOpen=

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dat\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{34FF1CFF-E5CB-4F98-8697-58D64007E7F4}
  (Default)=DataFileShellExtContextMenuHandler.FileContextMenuExt

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{34FF1CFF-E5CB-4F98-8697-58D64007E7F4}
  (Default)=DataFileShellExtContextMenuHandler.FileContextMenuExt Class

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{34FF1CFF-E5CB-4F98-8697-58D64007E7F4}\InprocServer32
  (Default)=D:\ShellExtTest\x64\Release\CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll
  ThreadingModel=Apartment
```

I don't know why it works for some file types but not another one. If anyone has an idea of what the problem might be, or how I can investigate it further, please let me know.

I've linked to the code, explained my system, what I do, and the problem I have, if you need any more information then please ask and I'll provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't say which registry keys you set and what you set them to. You also didn't say whether your DLL got loaded at all.

Comment: Did you notice that `.dat` files are marked `NoOpen`?

Comment: I've edited my question and added how the registry is setup when registered for .dat files. They are not marked as NoOpen in my registry, what I've listed is all there is for .dat files.

Comment: Your machine has somehow been changed from its default configuration. `.dat` is supposed to be `NoOpen` and it's not supposed to have a progid of `datfile`. Note also that we prefer to see code rather than prose.

Comment: It didn't work with the default configuration, I deleted my .dat registry key so the shell extension registration would recreate it, this is why it's different. Is there something special about this file type that it works differently to others?

Comment: I've put my registry settings for .dat files back to their default configuration, and updated my post to show how it is set up. It still has the problem of the context menu not appearing for this file type.